# Find intersection of two columns in Python Pandas -> list of strings

Tags: python, list, pandas, unique

I would like to count how many instances of column A and B intersect.
The rows in Column A and B are lists of strings.
For example, column A may contain [car, passenger, truck] and column B may contain [car, house, flower, truck]. Since in this case, 2 strings overlap, column C should display -> 2

I have tried (none of these work):

```
df['unique'] = np.unique(frame[['colA', 'colB']])
```

or

```
def unique(colA, colB):
    unique1 = list(set(colA) & set(colB))
    return unique1

df['unique'] = df.apply(unique, args=(df['colA'], frame['colB']))
```

TypeError: ('unique() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given', 'occurred at index article')

Comment: [mcve] with reproducible code sample, please?

Comment: What exactly would you like me to add? I used the code above and provided the error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe need `length` with [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection) in list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = [len(set(a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
```

Or:

```
df['C'] = [len(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[['car', 'passenger', 'truck'], ['car', 'truck']],
                        'B':[['car', 'house', 'flower', 'truck'], ['car', 'house']]})
print (df)
                         A                            B
0  [car, passenger, truck]  [car, house, flower, truck]
1             [car, truck]                 [car, house]

df['C'] = [len(set(a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
print (df)
                         A                            B  C
0  [car, passenger, truck]  [car, house, flower, truck]  2
1             [car, truck]                 [car, house]  1
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I was exploring your solution and functionally it works.
But on big data frames it is not fast enough for my use case.
I am new to Pandas, so do you think there is a possibility to speed this up, with some data manipulation ?
I was thinking to transform the lists in Series of Series 
( stack_query_time_categorical = only_categorical['A'].apply(pd.Series).stack().astype('category') )
But then I am struggling to calculate the intersections between them for all the values.

Comment: @AlessandroBenedetti One alternative method is based on what you tried to do with `df.apply`. You could have done: `df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x["col1"]) & set(x["col2"])), axis=1)`. However, I tested it, and ths is actually slower than the list comprehension method in this answer (15ms vs 370ms on a long df). The problem is pandas isn't designed to do vectorised operations with arrays of objects such as lists. You might be hard-pressed to find a faster way to do this.